# Zurb Foundation 5.1.1 Javascript bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I wanted to design a basic website or basically edit one of zurb foundation's templates. So I download the zurb foundation package and edit the code. Everything seems to be working fine but when I refresh the page . Some Jquery elements don't seem to work.

Eg : I had a carousel implemented and upon refresh , the indicators are not showing and it resizes automatically .

However , everything jumps back to normal like it should when

1. I open up the Inspector
2. I resize the browser and back again.

This is quite a bizzare experience. I have used bootstrap before and never seen it . Any leads  to how this can be solved or is this a bug in the foundation docs ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a known issue with 5.1.1.

See https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/4466

I had a similar problem - this only occured when using the non-minified scripts.

To fix the problem I manually incorporated the changes made in this commit:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/4436/files